# Pattern validation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I want a pattern with letters and numbers only.

This is how I do it...

JavaScript file:

```
var pattern_checked = checkPattern(); 

function checkPattern(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("name");

        var pattern = elem.getAttribute("[a-zA-Z0-9_]");
        var re = new RegExp(pattern);
        if (re.test(elem.value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But in both the cases, I'm getting false.

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Can you  post your html also .Are you sure you have attribute like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` this in your html .i think its a `pattern attr`

Comment: Did you check what `elem.getAttribute("[a-zA-Z0-9_]")` will return???

Comment: I guess your pattern is the attributes value. `elem.getAttribute("attributeName")` would return your pattern.

Comment: @prasad I think I'm doing something wrong. How do I use that pattern?

Comment: yes you are doing wrong .That why  i was asking the html code @ishanshah

Comment: @prasad I was using the method wrongly. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you meant to do:

```
function checkPattern() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("name");

    // Allow A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and underscore. Min 1 char.
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/;

    return re.test(elem.value);
}
```

Comment: `re.test()` will return boolean value. Just return it.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

[Example fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/u0xox431/)

Your problem should be at this line.

```
var pattern = elem.getAttribute("[a-zA-Z0-9_]");
```

Attribute should usually have a name with value. But from your example, it seems like the value is also name.
The HTML code should be something like below:-

```
<input type='text' id='name' pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9_]'>
```

Then to get the pattern

```
var pattern = elem.getAttribute("pattern");
```

Comment: Yeah got it! I didn't mention pattern in html file.

Answer (score 1):

With pure jquery/js it is possible:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Ex 15.04.2023" class="date" required pattern="\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4}"/>


css:
.date:invalid{
    background:red !important;
}

script:
$('.date').keyup(function(){
  console.log($('.date:valid').length)
});
```

Comment: For some reason, an empty input will validate my regex, so I should also check to make sure that my input`.value` is not equal to `""`.